# Accepting one's own answer does not move it to the top of the answers list

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer, original-poster

I have the following question: *[Display Alternative Content for Users with AdBlockers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625514/display-alternative-content-for-users-with-adblockers)*. I've posted my own solution after a while and accepted it.

The expected behavior is that even though it doesn't have the highest vote count, it's on top of the list since it's accepted and should be correct, (like it does on normally accepted answers), but if the accepted answer is my own (a.k.a. OP), it doesn't move to the top of the list, staying somewhere near the bottom with the lower voted answers.

Why is that so? Is it a bug or is it by design?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design.

Some users will accept their own answers to get the experience. To prevent gaming the system, self-accepts:

- don't float to the top
- don't award you 15 xp reputation for getting accepted
- don't award you 2 reputation for accepting an answer

*Answer adapted from [an answer on Meta Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3377/34364)*

Comment: It seems like you should get at least a little bit of reputation for answering you own question, as long as it isn't deleted/closed.

Comment: IMO, this rule does not make sense. The answer marked as solution by the asker should be pinned to top, no matter who submitted it. The asker knows best. I've seen many cases where the answer marked as solution IS the correct solution. Voting for an answer is often simply a casual "i like this", not "i believe this is the solution".