# Accepted Answer not on top

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

In this question: [Adding points to the left side of a chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577746/adding-points-to-the-left-side-of-a-chart)

The Accepted answer is floating along with other answers (sometimes on the 2nd level, sometimes it is the third answer), why is it treated as ordinary answers? Shouldn't it be a fixed top answer?

Comment: actually for me the accepted answer **is** in the top and the second answer got a bounty...

Comment: Oh, so is there a fight among the Bounty answer and the accepted one? @Vogel612..

Comment: @Vogel612 You must be sorting by "active". The accepted answer is (currently) at the top with that sort mode on, but it's not *pinned* to the top. If you switch to sorting by votes or by oldest, you'll see it move around.

Comment: If you keep refreshing the page the order will change.  Answers with the same vote count are ordered randomly to give them an equal chance of being seen first, and accepted self-answers aren't pinned to the top (and apparently answers awarded bounties are not pinned either).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/186560): "*[When accepting] your own answer: There is no reputation awarded and **the answer does not float to the top of the list.***"

Comment: @SamIam EEG --> short for electro-encphalogram. this is a brain-activity-scan with the help of electrodes that are pinned to you skull. i am fine too

Comment: This question tends to be asked repeatedly. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128421/238706

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Accepted self-answers aren't pinned to the top.

As for it floating around, the order of answers with the same number of votes is randomized when you're sorting by "votes".

Comment: Oh! That's the answer :) So they all have the same votes + It is a self-accepted! So it will not be fixed. It works this way?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Correct. This is intended behaviour.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan that's [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: IMO, this rule does not make sense. The answer marked as solution by the asker should be pinned to top, no matter who submitted it. The asker knows best. I've seen many cases where the answer marked as solution IS the correct solution. Voting for an answer is often simply a casual "i like this", not "i believe this is the solution".